# Nokogiri: How does nested xpath access outer loop?

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

Trying to get my head around Nokogiri and XPath, and hoping you can help explain this behaviour.  This code:

```
data = Nokogiri::XML(%{
  <veg>
    <peas>
      <color>"green"</color>
    </peas>
    <peas>
      <color>"yellow"</color>
    </peas>
  </veg>
})

data.xpath('//peas').each do |p|
  puts p                            
  puts p.xpath('color/text()')        
  puts p.xpath('//color/text()')    # output not as expected 
end
```

Gives this output:

```
<peas>
  <color>"green"</color>
</peas>

"green"

"green"
"yellow"

<peas>
  <color>"yellow"</color>
</peas>

"yellow"

"green"
"yellow"
```

How does puts `p.xpath('//color/text()')` end up retrieving both green and yellow, while p only contains one or the other?

Comment: That's a common XPath newbie mistake, thinking `//node` actually means `.//node`.

Comment: Unless you absolutely have to know XPath, I recommend using CSS with Nokogiri. CSS accessors are simpler, and easier to read for the most part. XPath is capable of very complex searches though, so I use it for those special occasions. Try `data.search('peas color').map(&:text)`.

Comment: @MarkThomas Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's breaking down the `<peas>` nodes into p, and iterating through them, it is first displaying the node itself

```
<peas>
  <color>"green"</color>
</peas>
```

and

```
<peas>
  <color>"yellow"</color>
</peas>
```

and then the `<color>` node's text of each p as well.

THEN, we get to `//color/text()`, and '`//`' says start over at the root, and get all `<color>` nodes, and the `text()` associated with them, which is why you get both Green and Yellow colors, even while iterating through each `<peas>` node separately.

So for another example, if we had iterated to the node `veg/peas[color='green']`, and then said find `//peas`, we would get back both `<peas>` nodes for yellow and green.

`color/text()` says "start from current node, and grab me the text of the child node `<color>`"
and `//color/text()` says "give me the text of all `<color>` nodes in the XML, regardless of current location"

Let me know if I need to clarify anything...